# How to require multiple controllers with express?

Tags: javascript, node.js, express

So I try to make a full stack project. It has controllers like signup, login, profile etc.

What I do is  I require each controller manually, then use them according to the request. For example, I will have

```
app.use('/signup',signup);
app.use('/login',login);
app.use('/profile',profile);
```

However, when I build up the complexity of the project,more controllers will be needed, but manually typing everything is not the best practice.

I want to have a more general form, just one line does all the work:

```
app.use('whatever the link i got',load the corresponding controller);
```

Maybe the solution will be in different form. How can I achieve this? I need some suggestions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The simplest solution would probably be to put them all in a `controllers` directory and then just do this:

```
const controllers = readdirSync(path.join(__dirname, 'controllers'))
controllers.forEach(controller => {
  app.use(`/${controller}`, require(`./controllers/${controller}`))
})
```

This works great, as long as your routes and controllers are named the same thing. If you need to deal with converting kebab to camel case, there's always [lodash](https://lodash.com).

Assuming you're using express 4, you could take this one step further, and put an `index.js` in the controllers directory. Inside:

```
const express = require('express')
const router = express.Router()

const controllers = readdirSync(__dirname))
  .filter(f => f !== 'index.js'))
controllers.forEach(controller => {
  router.use(`/${controller}`, require(`./${controller}`))
})

module.exports = router
```

Then you can just use the router like this:

```
app.use('/', require('./controllers'))
```

Comment: I believe it should be f => f.endsWith('.js'), not !, Also when i use this code, it says Router.use() requires middleware function but got a Object. Need help

Comment: @jianchengwu Sorry, copied that from a project that had each route in it's own directory. I fixed the answer above; give that a try. Also, make sure you don't have anything other than the controllers and the index.js file in your controllers directory.